# Using R to do aggregation like tapply in matrice rowwisely

Tags: r, apply, rowwise

I have a problem in doing matrix computation, could you please shed some light upon it.
Thank you very much in advance!

I have a data frame genderLocation and a matrix test, they correspond to each other with the index

> genderLocation[,1:6]

```
          scanner_gender cmall_gender wechat_gender scanner_location cmall_location wechat_location
    156043              3            2             2             Guangzhou           Shenzhen            Shenzhen
    156044              2           NA            NA             Shenzhen           <NA>                
    156045              2           NA             2             Shenzhen           <NA>            Hongkong
    156046              2           NA             2             Shenzhen           <NA>            Shenzhen
```

> test

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
    [1,]  0.8  0.7  0.6  0.6  0.7  0.7
    [2,]  0.8  1.0  1.0  0.6  0.7  0.7
    [3,]  0.8  1.0  0.6  0.6  0.7  0.7
    [4,]  0.8  1.0  0.6  0.6  0.7  0.7
```

Now I wanna aggregate genderLocation, compute the averages of their corresponding digits in matrix test. 
Take 156043 row for example, the results should be

```
      2    3 Guangzhou Shenzhen 
    0.65 0.80 0.60 0.70
```

I dont know how to do it using the apply family(as it is not suggested to using for-loops in R).
This seems to be

```
    > apply(test,1,function(tst,genderLoc) print(tapply(tst,as.character(genderLoc),mean)),genderLocation)
```

but I cannot understand the results, if limiting to the first 2 rows, it seems understandable.

```
    > apply(test[1:2,],1,function(tst,genderLoc) print(tapply(tst,as.character(genderLoc),mean)),genderLocation[1:2,])
           c("2", NA)       c("3", "2") c("广州", "深圳")     c("深圳", "")     c("深圳", NA) 
                 0.65              0.80              0.60              0.70              0.70 
           c("2", NA)       c("3", "2") c("广州", "深圳")     c("深圳", "")     c("深圳", NA) 
                  1.0               0.8               0.6               0.7               0.7 
                      [,1] [,2]
    c("2", NA)        0.65  1.0
    c("3", "2")       0.80  0.8
    c("广州", "深圳") 0.60  0.6
    c("深圳", "")     0.70  0.7
    c("深圳", NA)     0.70  0.7
```

##### FYI

```
    test=matrix(c(0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8, 0.7,1,1,1, 0.6,1,0.6,0.6, 0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6, 0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7, 0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7),nrow=4,ncol=6,byrow=F)
    genderLocation<- data.frame(scanner_gender=c(3,2,2,2),cmall_gender=c(2,NA,NA,NA),wechat_gender=c(2,NA,2,2),
                                 scanner_location=c("Guangzhou","Shenzhen","Shenzhen","Shenzhen"),
                                 cmall_location=c("Shenzhen",NA,NA,NA),
                                 wechat_location=c("Shenzhen","","Hongkong","Shenzhen"))
    genderLocation1<-cbind(genderLocation,test)  # binded for some apply functions only accepting one input.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for your example data *but I don't know how stable it is with all of your data*. An issue may occur if some of your rows in `df` do not share a common value with other rows. However, if you want to keep your output as a list, this should work with no problems (that is, skip `Reduce...`). Keeping that in mind...

**--Your data--**

```
test <- matrix(c(0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.7,1,1,1,0.6,1,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,rep(0.7,8)), nrow=4)

df <- data.frame(scanner_gender=c(3,2,2,2),
             cmall_gender=c(2,NA,NA,NA),
             wechat_location=c(2,NA,2,2),
             scanner_location=c("Guanzhou","Shenzhen","Shenzhen","Shenzhen"),
             cmall_location=c("Shenzhen",NA,NA,NA),
             wechat_location=c("Shenzhen",NA,"Hongkong","Shenzhen"),
             stringsAsFactors=F)
rownames(df) <- c(156043,156044,156045,156046)
```

**--Operation--**

I combine `map` from `purrr` with other `tidyverse` verbs to *1)* create a 2-column data frame with `df` `row-entry` in first column and `test` `row-entry` in second column, *2)* then `filter` out where `is.na(A)==T`, *3)* then summarise the `mean` by group, *4)* then `spread` into rowwise data frame using `A` (keys) as columns

```
L <- map(1:nrow(df),~data.frame(A=unlist(df[.x,]),B=unlist(test[.x,])) %>% 
              filter(!is.na(A)) %>%
              group_by(A) %>%
              summarise(B=mean(B)) %>%
              spread(A,B) )
```

I then reduce this list to a data frame using `Reduce` and `full_join`

```
newdf <- Reduce("full_join", L)
```

**--Output--**

```
    `2`   `3` Guanzhou Shenzhen Hongkong
1  0.65   0.8      0.6     0.70       NA
2  0.80    NA       NA     0.60       NA
3  0.70    NA       NA     0.60      0.7
4  0.70    NA       NA     0.65       NA
```

Comment: Thank you Chi Pak! It works for me.By the way, I am using the this package for a test, it costs 30 mins for 175999 rows, about the same  as using for-loops.

Comment: You can close this question by accepting an answer (check mark to the left) or you can keep this question open if you are looking for other answers. You can also change your accepted answer in the future as well